# Constant current LED driver min / max current rating explanation

Tags: led, current, constant-current

I currently have a 150-1500mA led driver that I sue to power a 30W LED. Driver has adjustable maximum current pins that I can use to change to match the maximum current. I have it set to 1050mA.

I am now considering another driver. Looking into [Meanwell LDD-350L datasheet](http://www.meanwell.com/search/LDD-L/LDD-L-spec.pdf) there is this line at the top of the first page:

> constant current output: 300mA to 700mA.

This confused me since what use is PWM dimming if you cannot get the full range of values? My current driver has minimum of 150mA but I am able to PWM the LED at very low levels, certainly below 150mA unless the driver is using up the remainder of the power.

How does min / max current specification work in constant current drivers?

**Edit:**

To add to the answer already accepted, the reason why my current LED driver was rated 150-1500mA is that it has max current select jumpers with 150mA being the smallest selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That datasheet is for multiple devices. The LDD-300L is capable of 300mA. The LDD-700L is capable of 700mA. Your device, the LDD-350L, is capable of 350mA. The second page describes the LDD-1000L through LDD-1500L. So the minimum and maximum are for the *range of devices*, not just a single device.

Comment: Ahh, how did I miss that... Thanks for pointing it out!